# How to lock formula when adding column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to keep an average of the 5 newest values of a data set: `Average($d$1:$h$1)`. If I add a new column to the left of D for new data, the formula changes to `($e$1:$i$1)`. How do I prevent the formula from changing?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=average(offset(A1,0,4,1,5))
```

(But don't add a column to the left of D that is to the left of A also!)

Help with =offset, and other functions, is available via Help and Function list.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much